# mosquitto pub-sub clients with Watson IoT platform

Tags: ibm-cloud, mqtt, mosquitto, watson-iot

I created two devices to simulate a pub-sub scenario with `mosquitto_pub` and `mosquitto_sub` commands. The dashboard shows connected status for the terminal running `mosquitto_sub`. The dashboard also shows the latest message sent by the terminal running `mosquitto_pub`. And, yet the terminal running the subscription shows nothing.

What am I missing?

**Subscription**

```
mosquitto_sub -h orgId.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -p 8883 -i d:orgId:dType:device01 -u use-token-auth -P token --cafile messaging.pem -t iot-2/evt/data/fmt/json
```

**Publisher**

```
mosquitto_pub -h orgId.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -p 8883 -i d:orgId:dType:device02 -u use-token-auth -P token --cafile messaging.pem -t iot-2/evt/data/fmt/json -f some.json
```

Answer (score 2):

you cannot use a device clientID (e.g. d:orgId:dType:device01) to subscribe to a topic of a deviceid, that is not allowed. You need to use an application for this actions.

Check here for credentials and authentication:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/applications/mqtt.html#mqtt

Command should look like:

```
mosquitto_sub -h orgId.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com -p 8883 -i a:orgId:myapp -u <api-key e.g a-orgId-a84ps90Ajs > -P <api-token> --cafile messaging.pem -t iot-2/type/dType/id/device01/evt/data/fmt/json
```

Comment: So if I had a "subscribe only" device, I have to treat it as an application?

Comment: yes. The only topic to which a device can subscribe to is a command topic:

iot-2/cmd/command_id/fmt/format_string

Ref: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/devices/mqtt.html#mqtt